# How to do gourad shading of a triangle or a plane whose three points are given with their respective color?

Tags: javascript

How to do Gourad shading of a triangle or a plane whose three points are given with their respective color?

triangle ABC

point A has coordinates x1,y1 and color r1,g1,b1

point B has coordinates x2,y2 and color r2,g2,b2

point C has coordinates x3,y3 and color r3,g3,b3

Can anybody help

Using Javascript only

Comment: Ok. if is like that can you provide a link for that as i haven't got it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, sure. Here's an implementation in C: http://www.nbb.cornell.edu/neurobio/land/oldstudentprojects/cs490-95to96/guo/report.html

If memory serves me correctly, you'll also find one in the Quake &/or Quake2 source code releases.

To be honest, it's been about 18 years since I last implemented it. Back in a time that 3d  cards were beginning to emerge for consumer computers. Now of course, there's a hardware implementation in even on-board graphics chips available to both directX and openGL.
There is of course, the ability to leverage openGL from within a webpage, using WebGL.

The algorithm is really quite simple and straight forward. You render horizontal lines. Each line has a start-colour and an end-colour. You simply interpolate colours between these two points. In order to get the start-colour and end-colour for each horizontal line, you interpolate the colours given at each vertex.

It's just linear interpolation of the colour itself - the colours are only calculated at each *vertex* from the face-normal and the light-vector, unlike the Phong model, which interpolates the incident angle, which is then used to calculate the colour at each *pixel*. (Phong allows specular highlights in the middle of polygons, Gouraud allows them when a vertex is contained within the highlight area. Gouraud is also clearly much cheaper to compute, on account of 3 dot products per triangle, vs a dot-product per pixel for phong)

A rough example using 1 component, ragther than 3

```
?...?
.....
.....
.....
?...?

1...?
.....
.....
.....
5...?

1...2
.....
.....
.....
5...3

11122
22222
33322
44433
55433
```

It's quite satisfying to implement from only a description of the algorithm.
A couple of resources which you may find helpful:

shaderToy (webGL demo) - http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/

js example of Gouraud shading - http://eng-przemelek.blogspot.com.au/2010/05/gouraud-shading-in-javascript.html

Have fun!